# ajax work only for first row of table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I'm using asp.net MVC3
In my view i'm displaying a table
in table i have a link for each row called "Attach a File"
this link will call controller function through the ajax call

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CourseID, new { @id = "CourseID", @Class="courseiding"})
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.PrtfID, new { @id = "prtfID" , @Class="prtfiding"})
@Html.ActionLink("Attach a file", "Index", null, new { @Id = "attchlink" })
```

ajax:

```
 $('#attchlink').click(function (e) {
        window.formCount = 0;
        e.preventDefault();
       var id = $('.prtfiding').val();
        var size1 = $('.sizing').val();
        var url2 = '@Url.Action("Index")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url2,
            data: { pid: id, size: size },
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

This is working for all the rows but while passing value in id and size...it is passing value of first row only for all rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Id attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp) of an element should be unique on a page.

Your problem is that you have multiple links with the same `Id = "attachlink"` and when you call `$('#attachlink')` jQuery just using the first one.

To solve this you should use classes instead of `Id`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Attach a file", "Index", null, new { @class = "attachlink" })

$('.attachlink').click(function (e) {

}
```

And then you can use the `.closest()` function to get the "colosest" values in your click event:

```
var id = $(this).closest('.prtfiding').val();
var size1 = $(this).closest('.sizing').val();
```

Alternatively you can put all the required data on the ActionLink in the form of `data-` attributes:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Attach a file", "Index", null, 
    new 
    { 
         @Id = "attchlink",
         data_courseID = item.CourseID,
         data_prtfID = item.prtfID
    })
```

And in your js function you can access them with:

```
var courseID = $(this).data('courseID');
var prtfID = $(this).data('prtfID');
```

If you don't need elsewhere the Hidden field you can remove them with this approach.

Comment: is it also aplicable to other controls??
lik i'm trying to access size and id of that appropriate row but it is giving me information of first row only

Comment: It's not clear what you meant on "aplicable to other controls". In general yes: when you have multiple elements on the page and you want all of them then use the `class` attribute. But if you want to mark an element and find that specific element use the `id` attribute.

Comment: In you specific case with #prtfID and #Size it's a little bit complicated. For solve this it's necessary to know how your view looks like, because in your click event you cannot use the id's directly and you need to find the right values in the DOM, but I think this is a different question.

Comment: i 'm actually sending id and size in that row as a parameter to my controller....but every time it is taking value of first row only...i changed my question...please have a lokk

Comment: Well my view looks like a normal table with fields...each row contain information for size which is diff from other row...but it is taking same value for all the rows

Comment: There are multiple solution, I've added one to my answer, another one is in this case to not use hidden fields and put the values as `data-` attributes on the `Action.Link`.

Comment: @nemsv: can u plese tell me sum othr method through which i can send data...this closest ids not working

Comment: @priya77 I've updated my answer with a solution using `data-` attributes.